# Styling cannot be applied to button - React Hooks

Tags: react-hooks

I'm using a resuable component for button wherein i wanna pass the color and bgColorvia props, color gets applied but then the background color doesnt apply

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {
    //width:'100%',
    margin: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  input: {
    display: "none"
  }
}));

export default function ContainedButtons(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const btnStyle = {
    color: props.color,
    backgroundColor: props.bgClrRed
  };
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        style={{ backgroundColor: props.bgClrRed, color: props.color }}
        fullWidth="true"
        className={classes.button}
      >
        {props.name}
      </Button>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        style={btnStyle}
        fullWidth="true"
        className={classes.button}
      >
        {props.name}
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm missing something I don't know what can anyone please lemme know

Updates

```
  import ContainedButtons from '../container/buttonsControl';
  import css from '../variable.scss';
```

Comment: How are you importing your `Button` and `makeStyles`?

Answer (score 0):

Try a spread operator:

```
style={...btnStyle}
```